# Drupal site blocked by Windows defender

Tags: security

Visiting my Drupal 7 site just now with IE 11, I get this message:

> Windows Defender blocked content on this website   lx7pyv.dofeqilr.com
>
> Hosted by: mysite.com 
>        Recommended icon Go to my home page instead     Windows Defender blocked this site because it might contain threats to your PC or your
>   privacy.

What's up? I get no hits when I search for "lx7pyv.dofeqilr.com". I also have not issues in Chrome or FF. Is my site infected?

Comment: This isn't exactly Drupal related, but it sounds like there may be some malicious code on your site.  I recommend posting to a websecurity related stackoverflow for the best answer.

Also it's impossible to answer you definitively unless you share the URL of your site.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had no idea to start. This was useful.

Comment: lx7pyv is a sub-domain and means nothing (this is common for spam) - do a whois search for the rest, it's out of the US in Hawaii (Registrant Name: Hoffmier, Jason). If your site allows users to post content, it could be a bot, or someone posted a link and Defender sees the link and determines it's possibly malicious...

Comment: I have done some digging, and it looks like it is the result of the Mailpoet bug on a Wordpress site I have on the same server.